# Varnish logged in user to remote server

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

On a varnish cache server, I would like to send all logged in traffic to a remote server, while keeping non-logged in users in the same server w/ varnish.
Currently, I have nginx web server running together with varnish. Port 80 is open to Varnish, and 8080 is given to nginx.

I've tried something like below, just to split the traffic.

```
`backend web1 {
    .host = "1.1.1.1";
    .port = "80";
    .probe = {
        .url = "/";
        .timeout = 1s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 5;
        .threshold = 3;
    }
}

   backend web2 {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
    .probe = {
        .url = "/";
        .timeout = 1s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 5;
        .threshold = 3;
    }
}`

sub vcl_init {
    new balancer = directors.round_robin();
    balancer.add_backend(web1);
    balancer.add_backend(web2);
}

sub vcl_recv {
    set req.backend_hint = balancer.backend();
}`
```

Web1 is to give traffic to remotely connected server via DHCP, and web2 is for the nginx server running the same server.

and for the logged-in users, I've tried with the suggestion given from [`this link`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341749/varnish-how-to-cache-logged-in-users).

so, if(req.http.Cookie) for 'SESSION_COOKIE', but I think, for my case, this should go to sub vcl_init, instead of sub vcl_recv. (and certainly not round_robin)

From this point, I have no idea how to set it up.

Answer (score 1):

While you're free to use `vmod_directors` for loadbalancing, you don't really need it. You can also explicitly assign backends in VCL.

Here's the VCL code I wrote to tackle the issue, based on your example code:

```
vcl 4.1;

import cookie;

backend web1 {
    .host = "1.1.1.1";
    .port = "80";
    .probe = {
        .url = "/";
        .timeout = 1s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 5;
        .threshold = 3;
    }
}

backend web2 {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
    .probe = {
        .url = "/";
        .timeout = 1s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 5;
        .threshold = 3;
    }
}

sub vcl_recv {
    cookie.parse(req.http.Cookie);
    if(req.http.Authorization || cookie.isset("SESSION_COOKIE")) {
        set req.backend_hint = web1;
    } else {
        set req.backend_hint = web2;
    }
}
```

My assumption is that logged in users either authorize themselves using the `Authorization` header, or using the `SESSION_COOKIE` cookie.

I'm using `vmod_cookie` to easily access cookie values. If you're on a (relatively) recent version of Varnish, this VMOD should be available.

If an `Authorization` header is part of the request or there's a `SESSION_COOKIE` cookie, we send the traffic to the `web1` backend, otherwise we send the traffic to the `web2` backend.

Of course you probably need to modify the code a bit, but you get the idea, right?

Comment: Yup! so vcl_init is not needed, or should I say 'embedded' in vcl_recv or 'combined' with vcl_recv. will check if 6.0.12 supports vmod, but even if not, it seems clear that I only have to handle cookie types. Thx bunch!

Comment: @Ubuntubasic1864 If you don't have `vmod_cookie`, just use a regex check on `req.http.Cookie` to check if the cookie is part of the cookie string.